# How to add an autocomplete field to a form

Tags: 7, forms

I've got a page that, in response to a button click, brings up a Bootstrap modal form.  In that form is a textfield with the standard Drupal autocomplete behavior; it's working fine.

I now want to set things up so that, after a value is put into that field, another mostly-identical autocomplete field is added to the form -- the idea is to let the user specify additional values for the property being handled by this part of the form.

I've hung a jQuery blur handler off the textfield that takes the HTML that ends up in the form for the initial autocomplete form, parameterizes it a bit to avoid duplicate ID numbers, and inserts this updated field into the form when the first field gets a value.  This is working fine from an HTML perspective, but the autocomplete behavior is not happening on the added form.

Minor notes:

- After I insert the new field into the form, I re-run `Drupal.attachBehaviors()`, which I thought was going to make this all work.  I've also added a delay to make sure the rewriting of the form is completed before `attachBehaviors()` is called, but that has no effect.
- The autocomplete behavior continues to work on the original field after the new field is added to the form.
- The blur handler that does all this stuff to the first autocomplete field is not firing when I blur control from the second, added field.

It looks like some other bit of initialization stuff needs to happen, but I have no clue what it is.  Does anybody else?  Thanks!

Comment: A minor update: I now have the blur handler firing on the newly-added field (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467550/how-to-initialize-form-additions-for-jquery-methods), but I'm not yet getting the autocomplete working on it...

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was pretty ugly, and a LOT of guesswork is going on here.  But:

When Drupal sets up an autocomplete field, it adds a hidden variable to the form, which (I'm guessing here) is used to track the status of the whole autocomplete thing.  If you inspect a rendered form, it will look something like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="edit-field-name-autocomplete" 
      value="https://example.com/path/to/autocomplete/handler" disabled="disabled" 
      class="autocomplete autocomplete-processed">
```

That `autocomplete-processed` field seems to be the key: I had blindly copied it into my code and made it part of the field I was added to the form.  Once I removed it -- `autocomplete-processed`, that is -- autocompletion ran properly on it and all other similar fields.

Whew.  Your mileage may DEFINITELY vary.